# adding click event in newly created div in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a new div on a click of button and inside that onclick function I am adding a click event to newly created div but its not working.

```
document.getElementById('blah').onclick = function(){
    var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(innerDiv);
innerDiv.onclick =createWorkFunction;
}
function createWorkFunction(e){
 alert();
}
```

can anybody quickly help me

Comment: Your code is working. http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/ttVZn/1/

Comment: That code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is corrct, But you did not set the text of the your `div` (an empty `div` can not be clicked by an user), Try this:

```
document.getElementById('blah').onclick = function(){
    var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    innerDiv.innerHTML = 'This is a div'; // set it's text
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(innerDiv);
    innerDiv.onclick = createWorkFunction;
}
function createWorkFunction(e){
    alert('this is some text');
}
```

Also it's better to use `addEventListener`

Comment: To use it where? And why is it better?

Comment: @Itay with `onclick` you can only attach a single event listener to the element but with `addEventListener` you can attach multiple event listener to it, also `onclick` is mostly used with old browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    var oBlah = document.getElementById('blah');
    oBlah.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(innerDiv);
    }, false);
    innerDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert();
    }, false);
})();
```

This should help.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
innerDiv.setAttribute("onclick","createWorkFunction()")   

function createWorkFunction(){
 alert("working");
}
```